# The second click on the button run the jquery function (not the first one)

Tags: jquery

I need to create a JS function to hide divs after click button. But the issue is it works after second click (first one it nothing happens).

I have buttons: #1, #2 and button id #hide_ico. After click #hide_ico button It should hide buttons  #1, #2. It happens after second click:

```
        $("#hide_ico").click(function(event) {
        var c = 'on';
        if ($("#1,#2").hasClass(c)) {
            $("#1,#2").hide();
            $("#1,#2").removeClass(c);
        } else {
            $("#1,#2").show();
            $("#1,#2").addClass(c);
        } 
    });
```

The second click should show buttons again. I create sth like hotspots on 3D view and need to these hotspots hide/show after click button named #hide_ico.

```
<button id="hide_ico" class="hide_ico"></button>
```

I think the problem is that the first click activate the group of buttons and the second click run the function. What I need to change to make it work correctly?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Because on first click `$("#1,#2").hasClass(c)` this is not true.

Comment: You can just do `if (!$("#1,#2").hasClass(c)) {`

Comment: 'if (!$("#1,#2").hasClass(c)) {' it works perfectly. But the second click should show the hidden buttons again. How to change the second part of the code?

Comment: You'll need to provide a complete snippet that demonstrates your issue and a clear explanation of what you want it to do.  See [mcve].  [edit] your question and click `[<>]`

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbra1dpv/) with some basic html/css to match your js.  It works as expected (with a css class you can see it add it on first click) (so not doing "nothing").  Change to `if (!$..` as above to hide on first click instead.  Clicking again shows.   Without more info from you, there's not much else we can guess at.   *Maybe* make sure your button is `type='button'` and not no type or submit, but that's unlikely the issue here.

Comment: You could add a counter `var counter = 0;` and use it with `toggleClass(!~counter++%3)`

Comment: Its because the `on` class is not present when it first starts. Just add it to the class and it should turn off after the first click

Comment: You could clean it up by using CSS instead of hide/show and `toggleClass` with the `hasClass` as the state parameter

Answer (score 1):

To make your links turn off on the first try you have to add the `on` class to the visible elements for the condition to be true after the first click.

```
<div id="1" class="on">First DIV</div>
...
if ($("#1,#2").hasClass('on')) {
```

You could also store a flag (`isOff`) as your state variable. Use the flag to change the classname in the view. And use CSS to modify how that "state" looks.

```js
/* JS */
let isOpen = false; // starts closed

const link = $("#hide_ico");
const divs = $("#1,#2");
const hide = $els => $els.toggleClass('off', !isOpen);
const toggleMenu = () => updateView(isOpen = !isOpen);
const updateView = () => {
  hide(divs);
  link.text(`${['Open', 'Close'][isOpen-0]} menu`);
}

link.click(toggleMenu)
updateView();
```

```css
/* CSS */
.off {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href=# id="hide_ico">Click me</a>
<div id="1">First DIV</div>
<div id="2">Second DIV</div>
```

If you use something like [markojs](http://markojs.com/) or React you would store a value in the state and render it in the template.

```html
<div classname=(state.isOff ? 'off' : '')>Second DIV</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is perfect. I see the difference now. Thank you for your time to help me. Have a nice day :)

Comment: You're welcome! I cleaned it up to clarify for others. Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of this case. And it is greate for using css to show/hide some divs or buttons. But how to use it for some function to run/stop, e.g. autorotate attribute for 3d model? It must be used the `modelViewer.autorotate='true/false'` to start 3d model rotation and click again make it stop. It would be so fantastic to use it again for another purpose.